# Foreach Condition with Ajax form submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I was trying to do for each condition for form but for some reason, it is submitting all foreach data with ajax.

```
@foreach($response['Types'] as type)
  <div class="option option-two">
    <div class="upper">
        <p style="font-size: 2em;font-weight: bold">${{ number_format($type['price']['subTotal'],2)}}</p>
        <p style="font-weight: bold">Per Day Parking</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <form name="{{$type['id']}}"  method="post" class="reds">
            @CSRF
            {{--<input type=hidden name=LotId value="{{ json_encode($response, true) }}">--}}
            <input type=hidden name=subtotal value="{{ number_format($type['price']['subTotal'],2) }}">
            <input type=hidden name=fees value="{{ number_format($type['price']['taxesAndFeesAmount'],2) }}">
            <input type=hidden name=total value="{{ number_format($type['price']['total'],2) }}">

            <button id="chkbtn" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">Add to Cart</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            $(function () {

                $("form[name='{{$type['id']}}']").submit(function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: '/options1',
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#iDiv").html(result);
                        }
                    });

                });


            });
        </script>
@endforeach
```

For some reason the response is

```
_token: Ve4UHceRA6OVYTdTzGdFvXxHkA14v74oy4Y4pCVz
subtotal: 23.90
fees: 4.99
total: 28.89
_token: Ve4UHceRA6OVYTdTzGdFvXxHkA14v74oy4Y4pCVz
subtotal: 23.90
fees: 4.99
total: 28.89
_token: Ve4UHceRA6OVYTdTzGdFvXxHkA14v74oy4Y4pCVz
subtotal: 27.90
fees: 4.99
total: 32.89
```

i want to send only one option data to the cart. But, its adding all foreach data to cart

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `type` in `@foreach($response['Types'] as type)` be `$type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: $('form').serialize()
```

This will serialize all forms mounted on the webpage. Instead you should serialize the submitted form only, just as you did for the submit event handler.

```
data: $("form[name='{{$type['id']}}']").serialize()
```

or shorthand

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

will serialize only particular form instead of all forms.

Comment: Given it's in the _submit_ handler for the form, you could also just use `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: agreed, that would also do.